# TIme Series forcasting

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, data-science, lstm

I've been following a lot of tutorials using lstms to forecast timeseries data. My question is that how do we predict on new data that is not part of the dataset since almost all the tutorials show the predict function in Keras being used on the test data split.
How do we actually forecast into the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you create your training data such that the model receives n points and predict the following m points. Once you have your model trained, you take the last n available points of your dataset or new points from the present, and the model will output a prediction of m points in the future.

If you want to predict more than m points in the future, you could predict m points and use it as input to predict another m points, and so on. However, you should be aware that using this technique you will probably get worse results as you are accumulating errors.

Comment: Does this mean that If i provide 60 days worth of testing data. Then the output of the predict function is predicting 60 days into the future?

Comment: Not really, it depends on how you have trained your model. Usually you have to provide to parameters: past-history (number of past points that the model uses to give a prediction) and forcasting horizon (number of future points to forecast). Then if you give the most-recent past-history points, the model will return a prediction of forcasting-horizone points in the future